# How to send a table-type in parameter to T-SQL while using C# IDataReader?

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, ado.net, sqldatatypes

I wrote a t-sql sp that gets a table as parameter.

I tried to call it from c#, but didn't know what type to use:

```
database.AddInParameter(command, "@ID", DbType.String, id);
database.AddInParameter(command, "@TemplatesIds", DbType.WhatType??, dt);

using (IDataReader reader = database.ExecuteReader(command))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
    }
}
```

What should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using a t-sql  then you can use SqlDbType.Structured if you're using a SQLCommand  under your (I'm guessing) IDbCommand

```
var dt = new DataTable();
... set up dt ...
par = new SqlParameter("@TemplatesIds", SqlDbType.Structured, dt)
```

There are quite a few examples of using this [here on the msdn.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)

Comment: What is the difference between DbType and SqlDbType? are there any more types?

Comment: SqlDbType are MS SQL Server specific

Comment: I had to do `par = new SqlParameter("@TemplatesIds", SqlDbType.Structured) {Value = dt};`.

Answer (score 2):

SqlDbType.Structured

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx

Answer (score 1):

maybe not the best approach, but works:

```
-- Create the data type
CREATE TYPE dbo.PlantList AS TABLE 
(
    plant_code char(1) Not Null Primary Key
)
GO
```

extension method

```
public static class DatabaseExtensions
{
    public static void AddTableTypeParameter<T>(this Database database, DbCommand command, string name, string sqlType, IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        PropertyInfo[] members = values.First().GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(member.Name, member.PropertyType);
        }

        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            var row = table.NewRow();
            row.ItemArray = members.Select(m => m.GetValue(value)).ToArray();
            table.Rows.Add(row); 
        }
        var parameter = new SqlParameter(name, SqlDbType.Structured)
        {
            TypeName = sqlType,
            SqlValue = table
        };
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }

}
```

and call as follows:

```
database.AddTableTypeParameter(command, "@region_filter_plants", "dbo.PlantList", regionFilterPlants.Select(p => new { plant_code = p }));
```